# How can I integrate both Java and Python in a Visual Studio project?

Tags: java, python, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm developing a software which involves database creation, manipulation and extension in a proprietary format, which is partly inspired from SQL but is more extensive.
Some part of my software is coded in Python, most in Java, and just a bit front-end in Visual Basic. How can I integrate the back-end code that is written in Python and Java, with VB (2012) and call functions among them, in a single solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach it by picking one of three languages as your database back-end, then develop an API for interacting between them using HTTP or some other protocol.

For instance, you could use Python [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com)'s great ORM to develop your database models, and then use the Django [Tastypie](http://tastypieapi.org/) library to expose API resources for your database models at endpoints like `http://localhost/api/v2/foo/` (a list of foo objects) and `http://localhost/api/v2/foo/24/` (a detailed foo object with `foo.id = 24`).

Then, write a class in your VB.NET App_Code folder called `localhostRESTfulApi` which consumes your django-tastypie API. This could be a simple or as complex as you want.

The simple case would include invoking API calls verbosely using something like `localhostRESTfulApi.POST([endpoint URL], [new object data])`. You have to be knowledgeable about how the POST/GET/PATCH requests work in all circumstances and it's not very OOP-y.

The complex solution would be to re-write wrappers for your objects in the django database back-end as classes in VB (and again in Java) which have a constructor that either takes `null` for a new object or `id` for an object which it would then retrieve via the API upon instantiation (e.g. by consuming the `localhostRESTfulApi.GET` method.  This way you save yourself some clunkiness by only having to write the API GET/POST logic in the private methods of the object class, instead of littered throughout your application.

You would also write a `save()` method which does the appropriate API PATCH/PUT request behind the scenes to sync with the database back-end -- or perhaps override your `get`/`set` attribute methods on the class to retrieve and save changes on-the-fly (without invoking an asynchronous `save()` method).

---

I'm curious to see what solutions other SO users come up with. This is merely one way I have done it previously on a multiple language/platform application (for which I also needed an external RESTful API anyway).